# Trying to save text box contents to a text file

Tags: c#, textbox, text-files

I am having trouble saving the contents of a text box to a text file.

I am gathering information about several repositories and printing the results to a text box and allowing the user to click a button to save the info.

Here is the code behind the button:

```
//create a folder on the user's desktop
        string saveInfoFolder = "C:/Users/" + Environment.UserName + "/Desktop/RepositoryResults";

        DirectoryInfo newDirectory = new DirectoryInfo(saveInfoFolder);
        if (!newDirectory.Exists)
        {
            newDirectory.Create();
        }

        //loop through each pathway and save to the text file (create it if necessary)
        string saveRepositoryResults = saveInfoFolder + "/RepositoryResults.txt";
        FileInfo RepositoryResults = new FileInfo(saveRepositoryResults);
        if (!RepositoryResults.Exists)
        {
            //update the text file with the details
            string createText = lstFileContents.Text;
            File.WriteAllText(saveRepositoryResults, createText);
        }
        else
        {
            string createText = lstFileContents.Text;
            File.WriteAllText(saveRepositoryResults, createText);
        }
```

This should work, right?  All I'm getting saved to the text file is the repository pathway and not the results.

Can anyone help me please?

Thanks! :)

Comment: Does it create the file ? What are the contents ? I just ran this on my machine and it worked. What are the contents of `lstFileContents.Text` ?

Comment: Yes, it creates the file, but only displays the pathways, not the information.  The user selects a text file that contains all the pathways (this has to be done each month), once the information (size, number of files, number of folders) is gathered, the text box displays all this data. The user can then save this.

Comment: @Mark So what is the problem?

Comment: @Mark This is very confusing (not sure what *"pathways"* are) ... Can we start with what's the value of `lblFileContents.Text` if you go through the debugger ?

Comment: The pathways are the locations of the repositories that I need to gather information from.  These are saved in a text file.

The user searches for selects this text file.

The computer will then gather the information needed and display it in the text box.

The user has the option to click a button to save this information to a text file.

When this information is saved, all that is saved is the pathway to each location.

Answer (score 0):

**C#**

```
using (System.IO.StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter(@"C:\Users\Public\TestFolder\WriteLines.txt", true))
{
    file.WriteLine(yourtxtbox.text);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string saveInfoFolder = string.Format(@"C:/Users/{0}/Desktop/RepositoryResults", Environment.UserName);

...

string saveRepositoryResults = saveInfoFolder + "/RepositoryResults.txt";

...

string createText = lstFileContents.Text;
System.IO.File.WriteAllText(saveRepositoryResults, createText);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks fine to write the text in file.But what is the value in Textbox.Text when you are trying to write its content in the file. Also you can change this if statement since else also works same.

```
   if (!RepositoryResults.Exists)
    {
        //update the text file with the details
        string createText = lstFileContents.Text;
        File.WriteAllText(saveRepositoryResults, createText);
    }
   else
   {
        string createText = lstFileContents.Text;
        File.WriteAllText(saveRepositoryResults, createText);
   }
```